# Qt Creatorでwindows版のビルド

Tags: qt5

Ubuntu14.04にQt Creatorをインストールしました。
クロスコンパイルがウリということなので、作成したアプリをWindowsでも使えるようにビルドを
したいと思い、Googleでいろいろ調べましたが、見つかりませんでした。
ツールキットに追加にWindows用のビルド環境を入れればいいように見えるのですが、やり方がわかりません。

Ubuntu用のQt Creatorとは別にwineでWindows用のQt Creatorをインストールし、Windows版を
ビルドする場合は、そちらで開くしか手がないのでしょうか？

Comment: 試していないのですが、この回答は参考にならないでしょうか。　http://stackoverflow.com/a/13211922/1205869

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
これだとコマンドラインでビルドすることになるのでできればキットを選択して
GUI上でビルドできればベストです。。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「クロスコンパイルがウリ」というのは聞いたことがありません。「クロスプラットフォーム開発」を誤解されているのではないでしょうか？

そうだとすると、その意図するところは、一つのソースコードから、ほとんど変更無し、またはわずかな修正や微調整くらいで、Windows、Mac OS X、Linuxに対応したプログラムが開発できるということで、コンパイル作業自体は、それぞれのOS用のQt Creatorを使用することになります。

まとめると、ひとつのOS上で多数のOS用の実行ファイルを生成するのではなく、それぞれのOS用のQt開発ツールを使えば、一つのソースコードから、多くのOS用の実行ファイルを生成できるという意味です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。すっかり誤解をしてました。
1つのOSしかもっていない人でもWindows、Mac OS Xで動くプログラムがコンパイルできると思ってました。
Windows用のQt Creatorをwineで実行し、コンパイルしたいと思います。